# Prove that the figure |x-p|+|y-q|=k represent a square

Tags: geometry, area

Prove that the figure |x-p|+|y-q|=k represent a square.

My approach is as follow

'k' is definitely greater than or equal to zero

Case I:

$x\ge p, y\ge q$

We get $\frac{x}{p+q+k}+\frac{y}{p+q+k}=1$

Case II:

$x\ge p, y<q$

We get $\frac{x}{p-q+k}-\frac{y}{p-q+k}=1$

Case III:

$x < p, y\ge q$

We get $-\frac{x}{k-p+q}+\frac{y}{k-p+q}=1$

Case IV:

$x< p, y<q$

We get $\frac{x}{p+q-k}+\frac{y}{p+q-k}=1$

Though I have approached upto here but still I cannot prove that this figure represent a square whose sides are inclined at $45^o$ and $135^o$ to the x-axis.

Is there any other short cut method to prove it

Comment: Are you sure you are not missing something else?
Can k really be 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make a substitute $z=(x-p)/k$ and $t=(y-q)/k$. It translate your figure to a square $|z|+|t|=1$ with center at $(0,0)$. So your initial figure is a square with center at $(p,q)$ and side $k\sqrt{2}$.